# Laravel before/after validation message

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel you can make a custom messages for validators. But I found that the prepared messages are little bit wrong. With `before` and `after` validation rules, the parameter is converted with `strtotime` like that said in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-after).

So if I set rule `'expires' => 'before:+1 year'` the rule is working and correct. But if the user inputs a wrong value, Laravel prints the message like that:

> The expires must be a date before +1 year

This message is very unclear for the average client. I was expected that the message will be converted with the `strtotime` also.

There is a clean way to print more clear error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the validation messages with a custom ones if you want to.

In the Form Request class, add the following method and change the messages like so:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        // 'fieldname.rulename' => 'Custom message goes here.'
        'email.required' => 'Er, you forgot your email address!',
        'email.unique' => 'Email already taken m8',
    ];
}
```

Update:

If you want to change the global messages, you can open the validation.php file inside `resources/lang/en/validation.php` and edit the message there.

Comment: But instead of doing that for each validator, can I do it for after/before rules by default?

Comment: yeah, I don't see why not, these are just examples to give you the idea. Just change the field name and rule name and you should be good to go.

Comment: I understand that, but I have a lot of validators with `before` and `after`, I don't want to change them all manually....

Comment: What about a foreach loop?

Comment: I don't understand how foreach loop will help me. I have a lot of validatiors in different classes.  I want to change the `after` and `before` message so they will be calculated with `strtotime` and I want to do it globally.

Comment: I have no idea if you can set the messages globally.

Comment: I just remembered that you could change the messages globally inside the validation.php file. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can user AppServiceProvider.php
  and you can write your new validation rule there and set your error message in validation.php file
  /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
  /resources/lang/en/validation.php

Ex:

```
    Validator::extend('before_equal', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return strtotime(Input::get($parameters[0])) >= strtotime($value);
    });
```

and the message is

```
    'before_equal' => 'The :attribute field is only accept date format before or equal to end date',
```

Please try this and you can alter this to based on your require.